# Jquery Hide multiple rows have the same id

Tags: jquery

i have multiple rows with the same id and when used the jquery function :

```
hide();
```

it hide the first row only and ignore the rest rows.

Could you please tell how can i fix it ?

Thanks in Advance

Neveen

Comment: switch to using classes: ids are supposed to be unique

Answer (score 3, accepted):

T.J Crowder above is correct.

Another thing you may find useful in jQuery is the each() function.

```
$('tr.foo').each(
    function(object){
        // do more stuff
        object.hide();
    }
);
```

With that, you can apply conditional logic as well, maybe only hide the row if it's content contains a filter-word or something.

I didn't actually know that I didn't have to use the 'each'.  (thanks TJ)

Comment: You're welcome. :-) But actually, the above is incorrect. The first parameter that jQuery passes its `each` function (http://api.jquery.com/each/) is the *index* of the item. It sets `this` to point to the DOM element for that iteration (and also passes it as the second parameter, in case you've used `proxy` (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/) to set `this` to something else in the iterator function).

Answer (score 6):

You can't have multiple rows with the same ID, it's invalid markup. From the spec ([link](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/elements.html#concept-id)):

> The `id` attribute specifies its element's **unique identifier (ID)**. The value must be unique amongst all the IDs in the element's home subtree and must contain at least one character.

Instead, ensure that the IDs are unique or don't use IDs at all, use some other information they all share — a common `class`, or a common location (e.g., all children of the same `table` or `tbody`), etc. If they don't have a common aspect you can use, you'll need to give them one, but it *cannot* be a duplicated ID.

For instance, to hide all `tr` elements with the class "foo" you'd use:

```
$('tr.foo').hide();
```

More about the jQuery class selector (which is just the CSS class selector) [here](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/).

Comment: Thanks a lot T.J. Crowder , the rows has common class how can i use it to hide them?? Thnaks

Comment: @Neveen: I've put an example in the answer.